# Why is <CalendarStrip /> not working properly?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import CalenderCard from '../../component/CalenderCard';
import CalendarStrip from 'react-native-calendar-strip';
import moment from 'moment';
import {colors} from '../../../config/colors';

const Home = () => {
  const [newdate, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const calenderRef = useRef();

  const date = new Date();
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(Date);
  const datesWhitelist = [
    // single date (today)
    // date range
    {
      start: startDate,
      end: moment(endDate),
      //  start: (date),
      //end: (moment('1/12/2023'))
    },
  ];
  return (
    <View>
      <CalendarStrip
        selectedDay={selectedDay}
        ref={calenderRef}
        //scrollable={true}
        headerText={null}
        selectedDate={newdate}
        onDateSelected={value => {
          setDate(moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          console.log(value);
        }}
        getSelectedDate={value => console.log(value)}
        daySelectionAnimation={{
          type: 'border',
          duration: 200,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderHighlightColor: 'white',
        }}
        calendarHeaderStyle={{
          fontSize: 20,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
          color: 'black',
          alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        }}
        //   iconLeftStyle={{position:"absolute",top:-70}}
        //  iconRightStyle={{color:'white',backgroundColor:colors.primaryTheme,}}
        style={{height: 150, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10}}
        startDate={moment(date)}
        highlightDateContainerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: colors.secondary,
          paddingVertical: 10,
          height: 'auto',
          color: 'white',
        }}
        // dayContainerStyle={{paddingVertical:10}}
        highlightDateNumberStyle={{
          color: colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
          fontSize: 14,
        }}
        highlightDateNameStyle={{
          color: colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
          fontSize: 12,
          marginHorizontal: 1.5,
          padding: 5.5,
          borderTopEndRadius: 20,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
          borderTopRightRadius: 20,
        }}
        highlightDateNumberContainerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: colors.primaryTheme,
          borderRadius: 40,
          padding: 4,
          marginHorizontal: 10,
          minWidth: 30,
          minHeight: 30,
        }}
        datesWhitelist={datesWhitelist}
        useNativeDriver={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

This is my code.
[image: This is the output]

I can only click on the selected date. Whenever I click on any other day, it does not do anything. It should highlight that day, right? But it does not do that. I tried to console log and it seems the onDateSelected gets invoked only when I click on the selected date. How do I make it so that when I click on some day, it will make that the selected date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datesWhitelist` prop receives an

> Array of dates that are enabled

The `startDate` and `endDate` states in your current component are empty strings (for endDate, `moment` will return null). Thus, `datesWhitelist` disables everything other then the currently preselected date.

Thus, `you need to assign valid dates to startDate and endDate of datesWhitelist`.

For example, the following will allow you to selected dates starting from selectedDay until "2022-06-10".

```js
const datesWhitelist = [
    {
      start: selectedDay,
      end: new Date("2022-06-10"),
    }
  ];
```

If you want to allow to pick everything, just remove the datesWhitelist prop.